# for loop and head not working as expected

Tags: shell, unix

test.txt:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

test.sh:

```
for ln in $(head -3 test.txt)
do
    echo "New line: $ln";
done
```

I would expect:

```
New line: 1 1
New line: 2 2
New line: 3 3
```

...but the output is:

```
New line: 1
New line: 1
New line: 2
New line: 2
New line: 3
New line: 3
```

Changed to:

```
"$(head -3 test.txt)"
```

...leads to:

```
New line: 1 1
2 2
3 3
```

What's wrong with that? Obviously, the spaces are the problem. Any simple workaround? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read line-by-line, try this:

```
head -3 test.txt | while read line; do
  echo $line
done
```

In general, the shell tokenizes things using whitespace, so if you do this:

```
for ln in $(head -3 test.txt)
```

It ends up looking like this:

```
for ln in 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

...which is why you get the output that you got.